# В какой раздел реестра установщик windows регистрирует программу?

Tags: windows, реестр

В какой раздел реестра установщик windows регистрирует программу?

Comment: Куда ты пропишешь, туда и зарегистрирует.

Comment: @Janycz, А как добавить программу в "Установленные программы"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что видно в "Установка и удаление программ", прописывается в

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

Свои данные можно хранить почти где угодно, [@Janycz](/users/14422/janycz) прав. Обычно создают свой раздел в

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\
```